# Firebase Android data is being saved incorrectly

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase console]

The way data is being saved in Firebase is that the User ID is under each Push ID, whereas it should have been the other way around; that is Push ID under User ID.

What do I have to change in my code?

```
private void saveServiceDetails(){
    adService1 adService1 = new adService1(Name, Description, Category, downloadUrl, lat, lng);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Saving information..., please wait");
    progressDialog.show();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(adService1)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
....
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String key = databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).push().getKey();
databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child(key).setValue(adService1)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is "mDatabase"?

Comment: sorry my mistake, it should be your database reference